# How to await for mongoose queries to be populated?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, async-await, mongoose-populate

I have an `awaited` mongoose query that also populates some models.
But the sub-items don't seem to get populated until later.

Is there a way/need to double-await for subdocuments?
or a way to `flush` the query out?
I tried various versions of `async/await` and also `then` without success.

The data *does* show in the client so eventually the query resolves somewhere.
But it's not ready when I need to process it.

```
let list = await _mongo.find({ type: 'vlog', shelves: true })
      .populate('user')
      .populate({
        path: 'product',
        model: 'product'
      })
      .sort({ createTime: -1 }).lean().exec()

console.log('list ready', list)
```

however the product and user test as undefined.
even more oddly, somehow logging them seems to change them sometimes

when I step through with a debugger I just see some kind of buffered object
[image: debugger]

```
Logger.log('no product', doc.product)

/// logs out the product!
  {
    _id: ObjectID {
      _bsontype: 'ObjectID',
      id: <Buffer 5d c9 8d b7 9b d5 eb 20 8b 44 fa 7e>
    },
    store: ObjectID {
      _bsontype: 'ObjectID',
      id: <Buffer 5d e1 e2 bf 9b d5 eb 20 8b 44 fa 86>
    },
    name: 'Benefit Precisely My Brow Pencil No. 3',
    desc: '',
    content: 'This ultra-fine eyebrow pencil comes in eight easy-to-choose shades and draws incredibly natural-looking, hair-like strokes that last 12 budge-proof hours. A few strokes of the rich yet blendable colour will transform brows from shapeless and undefined to filled and defined eyebrows.',
```

```
list ready [
  {
    _id: ObjectID {
      _bsontype: 'ObjectID',
      id: <Buffer 5e fc a7 5d 09 b4 33 5b fd c0 35 8b>
    },
    user: {
      _id: [ObjectID],
      name: 'estpehaniatjuaca',
....
    hashtag: [ 'makeup ', 'tutorial', 'makeuphangout', 'makeupnatural' ],
    content: 'Makeup Hangout Natural',
    product: [ [Object] ]
  }
]
```

refs:

buffering
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#buffering
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: Could you edit your question and post one sample data from each collection. Ideally your code should work.There seems to be some issue with the data.